# How can i use session variable for login user check in asp.net MVC5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am going to create login and registration form but confuse about to use identity or something else like session variable.

Please answer which one is better for MVC5 Application

Answer (score 0):

You can declare authentication in config file and use [Authorize] in all get method.